# oracle decode with multiple values

Tags: sql, oracle

i want to decode the value like the below query:

```
select id,
       name,
       val 
  from table1 
 where id in (decode(1,0,0,1,('''4'',''5'',''6''')));
```

But i am getting no records (Records are actually available).
Is the decode functionality like `('''4'',''5'',''6''')` will works?

I tried but not working. Any alternative to do so?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you give a worked example?

Comment: very hard to figure out how to answer this...  please describe the data and the desired results.

Comment: For my decode function, i need to provide multiple 'result' values when 'expression' equal to 'search'.

Comment: `DECODE(SEARCH, VALUE0, THEN0, VALUE1, THEN1, VALUE2, THEN2,...)`

Comment: Your question is **not understandable**.  If you want an answer you must explain clearly what it is you are trying to achieve.  The easiest way of doing this is to provide us with some input data and your desired output data, preferably with some rules for the transformation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I understand what you're asking.  My best guess is that you want to return a collection.  For example, if you define a `NUM_TBL` collection

```
CREATE TYPE num_tbl IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
```

Then you can do something like this where your `DECODE` returns a collection of numbers

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  with x as (
  2    select level id
  3      from dual
  4   connect by level <= 10 )
  5  select *
  6    from x
  7   where id in (select *
  8*                 from table(decode( 1, 0, num_tbl(0), 1, num_tbl(2,3,4) )))
SQL> /

        ID
----------
         2
         3
         4
```